# Forcing users to change their password after a number of days with Rails/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 4 with Devise. I've been looking for a setting that forces users to change their passwords if it's older than 3 months, but I can't find anything in devise.rb (there are other settings to force changing passwords on first logon, etc.). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it is built in. You will have probably have to handle it yourself by time stamping when the password was updated and then check that against current time in the sign_in hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [devise_security_extension](http://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension), it's a [devise extension](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Extensions) that adds the functionality I think you are looking for.

Once you install it, you can then do

```
devise :password_expirable
```

and in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can add in (or uncommented depending how you installed it) the time frame you want to expire the password

```
config.expire_password_after = 3.months
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: when I follow your previous suggestion I get error like this: `undefined method `user_password_expired_path' for #<Home::SummariesController:0x007f88024ad4e0>` where Home::SummariesController is my home controller...any idea to solve it? I need some route declared?